# How can create haft part circle corner?

Tags: android

I need create a xml drawable background like this:

[image]

In that include black shape and transparent background.

I try but not yet resolve it. THis my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <size android:height="15dp" android:width="15dp"/>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/black"/>
            <corners android:topLeftRadius="0dp" android:bottomRightRadius="15dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <size android:height="15dp" android:width="15dp"/>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
            <corners android:topLeftRadius="15dp" android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

How can do this?
Have any suggest for me? thanks

Comment: Simplify your life and use a VectorDrawable. Simply sketch an SVG in Inkscape and then convet it to a VectorDrawable.

Comment: What is the problem? Your drawable file looks exactly like your image

Comment: oh i want the white shape is transparent. but in my code it is white. If i set color is transparent, the black shape will not like this